# php exec() not running via a cron job

Tags: php, bash, cron, raspberry-pi, gpio

I have been banging my head against this for hours now.

I am executing a php script via a cron job, everything in the script works except for the `exec()` method.

```
<?php
    exec('gpio write 7 0');

    // Open the file to get existing content
    $current = file_get_contents('log.txt');

    // Append a new person to the file
    $current .= get_current_user().' - '.date('H').":".date('i')." - gpio write 7 0\n";

    // Write the contents back to the file
    file_put_contents($log, $current);
?>
```

If I execute the php script directly from the terminal it works with both the `pi` user and with the `root` user.

The data that is being written to the `log.txt` file when the cron job runs looks fine to me, heres a sample:

```
root - 00:16 - gpio write 7 0
root - 00:17 - gpio write 7 0
root - 00:18 - gpio write 7 0
root - 00:19 - gpio write 7 0
```

I have tried giving the php file that is to be executed both `755` and `777` permissions with no luck.

This is what I have when I execute `sudo crontab -e`

```
*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/check_time.php
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be specific with your path for `gpio` and give the exact location so cron knows where to find it, `/usr/local/bin` is not imported by cron:

```
/usr/local/bin/gpio
```

So it will then be:

```
exec('/usr/local/bin/gpio write 7 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

on the line

```
exec('gpio write 7 0);
```

should it be

```
exec('gpio write 7 0');
```

? It appears that the the ' was never closed.

Comment: No that was a typo when I was writing the post. good catch though. I have updated the post accordingly. thanks

Comment: what computer/server OS are you running it on? It seems as though php is not executing the script. On newer ubuntu servers you can just use  `php` instead of `/usr/bin/php` in the cron script. Some of them get picky   
edit- i see you say you are running it on a ras-pi, give that a try